# Clean up SQL Code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have created a working SQL query but it's ugly. I am using the statement:

```
CASE WHEN p.Guests is null THEN 0 ELSE p.Guests
```

About 10 times in some calculations being done in the query and I am wondering if it is possible to do something like:

```
variable = CASE WHEN p.Guests is null THEN 0 ELSE p.Guests
```

and then instead of `123 * (CASE WHEN p.Guests is null THEN 0 ELSE p.Guests)`
I could do `123 * variable`. p.Guests is the number of guests attending an event and it varies based on each row in the query.
So my question is: is there a way to make a variable like this in SQL?

Comment: Why not use a subquery? `SELECT 123 * variable, 456 * variable FROM (SELECT variable = COALESCE(p.Guests, 0) FROM ...) AS x;`

Comment: ...even though you *can* simplify the expression, why repeat the expression multiple times regardless of complexity?

Comment: I'm using the expression at multiple points in the query. I'm pretty new to SQL so it may be the really long way to do it but it does what I want it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a long-winded case statement when there's

```
ISNULL(p.Guests, 0)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
select 123 * ISNULL(p.Guests,0) FROM ...
```

The `ISNULL` function will return the first parameter, unless it is `null` in which case it will return the second parameter.